# How to save file in windows 8

Tags: silverlight, mobile, windows-phone-8

Hello I'm learning windows phone 8 and i have problem with saving file, basicaly I'am downloading zip file from web service and i need to save it, but i was not able to do that. I want to save contents of inStream Any suggestions ?

```
private async Task saveSetupFile(Stream inStream)
    {

        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

        var myFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("AuditsSetupFiles", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);


        var file = await myFolder.CreateFileAsync("EquipSetup.zip", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        var outStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

        byte [] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
private async Task SaveSetupFile(Stream inStream)
{
    var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var folder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync("AuditsSetupFiles", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("EquipSetup.zip", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    using (var outStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        await inStream.CopyToAsync(outStream);
    }
}
```